# Troubleshooting atomic_set operation that causes kernel paging error request

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to troubleshoot an error that crashes a linux kernel driver I am programming.  The code worked fine on another machine.  I've migrated the same code to another machine and now it crashes.  I'm having a hard time troubleshooting what exactly the problem is.  I've narrowed it down to the following block of code.

```
mutex_lock(&(ctl->mtx));
atomic_set(&ctl->app.enabled, 1); // this line crashes it
mutex_unlock(&(ctl->mtx));
```

I've also tried the following.

```
mutex_lock(&(ctl->mtx));
atomic_set(&ctl->app.enabled, 0x01);
mutex_lock(&(ctl->mtx));
```

Below are the structs involved.

```
typedef struct ctl_struct {
    struct mutex mtx;
    struct app_struct app;
}

struct app_struct {
    atomic_t enabled;
}
```

Both lines of code produce the following

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 0000000000002c28
IP: [<ffffffffa02cd847>] mod_start_trace+0x157/0x1a0 [test_mod]
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.399186] PGD 7ef858067 PUD 7f06d2067 PMD 0
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.399830] Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] Modules linked in: test_mod     ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle bridge stp llc ebtable_nat ebtables ip6t_REJECT xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 ipt_REJECT xt_LOG xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_addrtype nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack xfs ip6table_filter ip6_tables nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables libcrc32c gpio_ich coretemp ast joydev lpc_ich ttm drm_kms_helper drm i5000_edac serio_raw edac_core i2c_algo_bit syscopyarea i5k_amb sysfillrect sysimgblt shpchp lp parport tpm_infineon mac_hid ipmi_si raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq raid1 mptsas hid_generic mptscsih raid0 e1000e multipath ahci usbhid mptbase ptp usb_storage psmouse hid libahci scsi_transport_sas pps_core linear [last unloaded: test_mod]
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] CPU: 3 PID: 2820 Comm: ctl Tainted:     G           O 3.13.11.4 #1
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] Hardware name: Sun Microsystems SUN FIRE     X4150/SUN FIRE X4150, BIOS 1ADQW068 11/16/2010
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] task: ffff8807ed7c5fc0 ti: ffff8807ef498000 task.ti: ffff8807ef498000
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa02cd847>]  [<ffffffffa02cd847>] mod_start_trace+0x157/0x1a0 [test_mod]
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] RSP: 0018:ffff8807ef499e88  EFLAGS: 00010246
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff88002bd3c000 RCX: 0000000000000006
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000046 RDI: ffffffffa02cfe71
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] RBP: ffff8807ef499ea8 R08: 0000000000000092 R09: 0000000000000afc
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffff8807ef499bb6 R12: ffffffffa02d1453
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] R13: ffff8807efe64160 R14: ffffffffa02d12a0 R15: 0000000000000000
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] FS:  00007fc797461880(0000) GS:ffff88081fcc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] CR2: 0000000000002c28 CR3: 00000007f1295000 CR4: 00000000000027e0
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] DR0: 00000000000000a0 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000003
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] DR3: 00000000000000b0 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] Stack:
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006]  ffff8807f0bef800 00007fc79747f000 0000000000000014 ffff8807efe64160
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006]  ffff8807ef499ed8 ffffffffa02ce368 ffff8807d1412480 00007fc79747f000
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006]  ffff8807ef499f50 0000000000000014 ffff8807ef499ef8 ffffffff812243ad
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] Call Trace:
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006]  [<ffffffffa02ce368>] mod_test_proc_control+0x548/0x5b0 [mod]
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006]  [<ffffffff812243ad>] proc_reg_write+0x3d/0x80
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006]  [<ffffffff811bcb54>] vfs_write+0xb4/0x1f0
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006]  [<ffffffff811bd589>] SyS_write+0x49/0xa0
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006]  [<ffffffff8172d42d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] Code: 44 e1 31 c0 48 c7 c7 10 f9 2c a0 e8 54 ad 44 e1 48 85 db 74 98 4c 89 e7 e8 57 5a 45 e1 49 8b 86 a3 01 00 00 48 c7 c7 71 fe 2c a0 <c7> 80 28 2c 00 00 01 00 00 00 31 c0 e8 28 ad 44 e1 4c 89 e7 e8
Dec 22 14:02:42 gol3430-01 kernel: [41114.400006] RIP  [<ffffffffa02cd847>] mod_start_trace+0x157/0x1a0 [mod]
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006]  RSP <ffff8807ef499e88>
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.400006] CR2: 0000000000002c28
Dec 22 14:02:42 test_server kernel: [41114.440174] ---[ end trace 37ddb83f133ddac1 ]---
```

I've had this error before and it was a problem with my code as opposed to the bios being out of date.  I've been doing some research and it I've just seen stuff on the bios.  I've just started programming with `atomic` operations and my attempts at troubleshooting have also caused problems.  Any help or what direction to start troubleshooting is greatly appreciated.  Again this code works fine on another machine.  Thanks!

Comment: Why would you think that on a memory access error changing `1` to `0x01` would make a difference? They have exactly the same value and type.

Comment: Its best if you can put the complete stack trace and share details along with the code ? How did you come to the conclusion that this block of code is having an issues ?

Comment: I didn't think it would make a difference I was just trying to try something else.  I came to the conclusion it was that block by working my way through the trace and disassembling the function to find that it was that line of code.  I also put a `printk` statement to the `kern.log` after that line and it doesn't make it to that `printk` statement.  Thanks again for the any help.